# Python- Convert Dict hidden in List to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble using the normalize in JSON for a dictionary that is being recognized as a list. The goal is to create a data frame from yahoo_finance.

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

ticker = 'AAPL'
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
balance_sheet_data_qt = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly', 'balance')

#The return is a bit messy, I've simplified it with:
user_dict=balance_sheet_data_qt.get('balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly').get(ticker)
df=pd.DataFrame(user_dict)
```

But Still having trouble taking the data across the finish line, the goal would be for each quarterly date as the index for each row, and the key finances listed as columns.

Comment: in your code all you are doing is calling a method, how we are suppose to understand your problem???

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the expected output ?

Comment: Currently the output looks like this:
                                          2018-03-31  \
0                                                NaN   
1                                                NaN   
2                                                NaN   
3  {'netTangibleAssets': 126878000000, 'totalCurr... 

Revenue   Total Revenue Cost of Revenue Gross Profit Operating Expenses  \
9/29/2018     265595000       163756000    101839000                NaN   
9/30/2017     229234000       141048000     88186000                NaN

Comment: The goal is to have the financial records in columns, and each data as the index of the row - in a dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You can use ChainMap from collections.

```
from collections import ChainMap    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ChainMap(*user_dict), orient='index')
```

If you don't want to use ChainMap, you can iterate through the dicts in user_dict (a list), and then append these DFs to the main df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for d in user_dict:
  df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index'))
```

ChainMap runs significantly faster for me

```
1.43 ms ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

vs

```
7 ms ± 121 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

The following has the date as index and the financial data in the columns:

```
dataframe_entries = list()
for result in balance_sheet_data_qt.get('balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly').get('AAPL'):
    extracted_date = list(result)[0]
    dataframe_row = list(result.values())[0]
    dataframe_row['date'] = extracted_date
    dataframe_entries.append(dataframe_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_entries).set_index('date')
```

Outputs:

```
date            accountsPayable               treasuryStock                     
2018-12-29      44293000000      ...          -3588000000
2018-09-29      55888000000      ...          -3454000000
2018-06-30      38489000000      ...          -3111000000
2018-03-31      34311000000      ...          -3064000000
```

Comment: when i try this it errors on line 3 
'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: You must be using python3 in this case. I have updated the code for this now.